# Multiple Patterns and substitutions with one regex

Tags: regex

I'm getting my old Wordpress-HTML posts ready to be migrated to my shiny new Markdown-based blog.

I convert one post at a time, doing some manually dusting off etc.
I've written a regex on regex101.com which substitutes  tags with the markdown-syntax.
Then I copy the substituted text again into another window which converts the  items.

Is is possible to match and substitute multiple patterns in one go?

Comment: Need more input to provide a decent response. Please show what you are doing and what outcome you hope for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subpatterns. Example:

```
$str = 'foo has a bar.';
echo preg_replace('/(.*?)( has a )(.*)/', 'hello $2 world', $str);
// Outputs: hello  has a  world
```

Sorry for the stupid example text but it should show what I mean.

Read more about subpatterns:  http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php